# Integrated Security when moving from IIS to Docker on Linux

Tags: linux, docker, linux-containers, integrated-security

My current services run on Windows in IIS.  I have them run as a Service Account user that is part of my Domain.  This user runs the app pool for the service and is also given the needed permissions to the database.  Then our connection strings can just use integrated security to connect to our SQL Server databases.

The benefit of this is that it can be setup in advance and the code/connection strings do not need to have any passwords.

As I am moving to docker containers I am finding this a difficult situation to keep using.  My containers run as root or some other non-company user.  So I can't just use integrated security.  (And even if I could make my containers run as a domain user, I don't know that it would be a good practice.)

**How can I keep passwords out of my database connection strings and configuration when running in containers?**

Comment: Am I correct to understand that "integrated security" is what Microsoft calls their spin on Kerberos? You do realize that Kerberos existed in the UNIX world _long_ before Active Directory existed, and it's still around and available to use today.

Comment: ...that said, generally, I'd suggest Hashicorp Vault if you're looking for a more modern secret-management stack designed for cloud use. That's a much broader question than is usually on-topic here (and closer to systems design or security than to programming; both of those fields have their own Stack Exchange site).

Comment: ...anyhow, if you were using a native-UNIX database, the krb5 connection / authentication / encryption method is where you'd find the Kerberos support.

Answer (score 6):

Couple options that might work depending on your specific scenario:

1. If you're connecting to on-prem SQL Server
   database you can can use Integrated windows auth with Kerberos - see
   [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1272546/Authenticate-Net-Core-client-of-SQL-Server-with-In) for implementation of a .NET Core app, running in a Linux container, connecting to a SQL Server database with integrated security.
2. You could also switch to SQL auth and get `User Id` and
   `Password` (or entire connection string) from Azure App Config /
   Azure Key Vault. *Note: in AAC, any secrets settings (e.g. API keys,
   SSH keys, etc) should be Azure Key Vault (AKV) references. AAC can
   integrate to AKV via managed identity.*
3. If you're using managed DB like Azure SQL Database you could connect
   using [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) with Azure Tenant ID & client ID/Secret (of AAD app registration)
   set as environment variables (see [EnvironmentCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-dotnet) which is the
   default credential type for DefaultAzureCredential). *Note: for local
   development DefaultAzureCredential will fallback to
   [VisualStudioCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.visualstudiocredential?view=azure-dotnet), which enables
   authentication to AAD from Visual Studio using user creds.*

Comment: This really helped. Thanks!